# Using VBA to insert formula - IF statement with blanks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using VBA to enter a formula into a range of cells. The formula is:

```
If VAT = "YES" Then
Range("G24:G47").Formula = "=IF(F24="","",G24*0.14)"
ElseIf VAT = "NO" Then
Range("G24:G47").Formula = "=IF(F24="","",G24*0)"
Else
'Do Nothing
End If
```

Basically it checks the variable VAT to see whether it is YES or NO and then inserts the corresponding formula. The issue is that the formulas for both options output as follows (I am using VAT = YES as the example): `=IF(F24=",",G24*0.14)`. The problem is that one `"` disappears from the logic step and the if true portion. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double all the double quotes used in the formula. e.g. "" would become """" and if you have something like "Yes" in the formula, it would become ""Yes"".

```
Range("G24:G47").Formula = "=IF(F24="""","""",G24*0.14)"
```

Comment: Legit! Could not figure that out for the last half an hour :( Thanks Nitesh! Will accept in 5 minutes.

Comment: Try using the macro recorder.  :)

Comment: Do not know why I didn't do that! Having one of those days man. Thanks for the answer and the kick in the nuts lol :P

Answer (score 0):

You can just straight ignore the NO like this :

```
If VAT = "YES" Then
Range("G24:G47").Formula = "=IF(F24="","",G24*0.14)"
Else
Range("G24:G47").Formula = "=IF(F24="","",G24*0)"
End If
```

otherwise

```
If VAT = "YES" Then
Range("G24:G47").Formula = "=IF(F24="","",G24*0.14)"
ElseIf VAT = "NO" Then
Range("G24:G47").Formula = "=IF(F24="","",G24*0)"
Else
 Exit Sub
End If
```

Whatever type of "code block" you're currently in, you have "Exit" the same kind, so "Exit Sub", "Exit Function", etc.

Comment: you haven't answered my question here. See below answer by Nitesh.